# Adding a column on row based operations in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark DataFrame where I am trying to create a new column based upon previous columns, but the tough part for me is that I have compute the value of the column row-wise. For example:

> col1 |col2 |col3
>
> 1    | 2   | 3
>
> 4    | 5   | 0
>
> 3    | 1   | 1

So, I want a  new column which has name of the column of the expression
max(col1, col2, col3) per row. So, desired output:

> col1 |col2 |col3 |col4
>
> 1    | 2   | 3   | 'col3'
>
> 4    | 5   | 0   | 'col2'
>
> 3    | 1   | 1   | 'col1'

Anyway it is possible to do in PySpark?

Comment: What would your desired output look like for the data you have posted?

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the desired output.

Comment: What if there is a tie? What if two numbers are the same?

Comment: The original problem statement takes care of this condition. No two columns per row have the same data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal answer, because it forces you to go back to RDDs. If I find a better one that allows you to stay in the `DataFrame` universe, I will update my answer. But this should work, for now.

```
a = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3],[4,5,0],[3,1,1]])
headers = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]

b = a.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2], headers[x.index(max(x))]))

b.toDF(headers.append("max_col")).show()
```

This basically allows you use the `max` operation from python by iterating through your RDD on a row basis. It then finds the right column by indexing the list of headers.

Again, I'm not sure this is the best way and I hope to find a better one.